# SharePoint Programming- Getting Started

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I'm fairly sure I know the answer to this, as I haven't been able to find anything yet, but is there any way I can get custom code onto the server without having any direct access to it?  I have Administrator access and can do much that way, but I can't actually access the system outside of SPD and the browser, as IT refuses to respond to my emails.  I am trying to do some things that seem beyond the scope of the built-in abilities of the system, but when I tried to do some coding, one of the first steps was to get a DLL from the server, and I couldn't find anything indicating that there would be much hope for getting my code up there.

**EDIT:**  I guess I should be a bit more clear, as I am not only looking for ideas as to how I can work on some code for the server, but also any sneaky ways to get code into SharePoint without dealing with them.  I had hoped I might be able to put a bit of custom code into a form, but that is not available on list forms, and I haven't yet worked enough with form libraries to see if it can be done there.

Comment: How is the title even remotely related to your question? :)

Comment: I couldn't think of anything better.  Plus, I'm trying to find out if I can get started programming for SharePoint... It's a LITTLE related... sorta

Comment: How about "Can I do "X" without direct access to the server" where you edit your question to describe the sort of thing you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your IT department has very good reasons for not giving you access to a production SharePoint environment.

If you want to start developing SharePoint solutions, the first step would be to ask for a development VM, or you can use a service like CloudShare, plus of course resolving the question of whether IT will ever let you put custom code up on the server or if there's a better way to get the functionality that you want.

Comment: The IT department isn't denying me access to the production environment- they're refusing to talk to me.  That would be a very good option, if I could get them to respond to my communications.  I have been trying to get ahold of them for almost a month now, and have yet to receive a response.  Apparently this is not abnormal here.  As for the CloudShare option, is that something I could get free access to?  Without hearing from IT, it's doubtful that I could get the company to foot the bill.

Answer (score 0):

As lgaud said you should [create your own SharePoint server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607866%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Since you dont have direct access to your SharePoint farm but you are a Site Collection administrator of your site collection you can take into consideration creating SharePoint 2010 Sandbox Solution.
[Getting to know Sandbox solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx).